# CSS of typeahead not working with turbolinks on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, turbolinks

The issue is regarding the movement of the text input box after pressing any link on the page.

**Turbolinks** is on.[If this line of code is removed the problem gets fixed]

```
//= require jquery.turbolinks
```

**Javascript** associated with the search box works ok:

```
var ready;
ready = function() {

        $('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
          ...
        });
}

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

Also on **reload** the "Before" state is restored.

The problem is specifically occurring with input boxes tagged with **typeahead**.

**Before:**
[image: Before]

**After:**
[image: After]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The search text field had the following Embedded Ruby initially:

```
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search],class: "address form-control" %>
```

Changing it to

```
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search],id: "address",class: "form-control" %>
```

fixed the problem.